# Is it NP-complete to find a sub-maximal clique which is at least max clique size - 1?

Tags: np, np-complete, clique, clique-problem

It is well-known that it is a NP-complete problem to find a maximal clique in a graph. But I wonder know if it possible to find a sub-maximal clique in a graph in polynomial time. That is, given that we don't know whether `P=NP` or not, is there a polynomial algorithm that would give me a clique whose size is **at least** the maximal clique size minus 1?

I guess the answer is "no", because I know that there isn't a polynomial-time algorithm that gives me a clique whose size is **exactly** maximal clique size minus 1 - otherwise I would know the size of max clique by this algorithm in polynomial time, which is impossible if `P!=NP`.

But I just don't know how to prove it when we expect the algorithm to return a clique with size **at least** maximal clique size minus 1 - say, it may randomly return a clique, whose size may be maximal, or may be maximal-1.

Is there any approach to prove its NP-completeness? Or such an algorithm really exists?

Comment: What you are looking for is a polynomial time algorithm that approximates the maximum clique with a guaranteed approximation quality. If you search for "max clique approximation" then you can find a lot of links that give the best approximation algorithms known (see for example the Wikipedia article). This may give further ideas in addition to the proof you already provided.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the answer by myself. The maximal clique problem can be reduced to this problem.

Given a maximal clique problem with graph `G`, we can duplicate the graph `G` to a new graph `G'`. Then combine the two graphs in the following manner: if there is an edge between two vertices in graph `G`, connect each pair of the two vertices in `G` and `G'`; and for each vertex in `G`, connect it and its duplication in `G'`.

Then, each clique in `G` of size `m` with its duplication in `G'` consist of a larger clique of size `2m`. So, there is a clique of size `m` if and only if there is a clique of size `2m` in `G'`.

So, to find the maximum clique in `G`, we just find the sub-maximum clique in `G'` and the clique must contains all vertices in the maximum clique of `G`. Thus, we know the maximum clique in `G` in polynomial time, which is only possible when `P=NP`.